# How to plot ellipse function and output vectorgraph as mathematica?

Tags: r

I have ellipse function as below:

```
−3.06274x^2−y^2+1192.22x+152.71y+1.829648xy −196494==0
```

I use `emdbook::curve3d(-3.06274*x^2-y^2+1192.22*x+152.71*y+1.829648*x*y-196494, sys3d="contour",level=0,from=c(200,200),to=c(500,500))` to plot it.
[image]
But there's a zero in the curve around x:260,y:400.
I just need a vectorgraph without axis,such like .eps. Then I can use illustrator to open this .eps file.
How to do it?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, did you try the method in your"duplicate" post? Doesn't work!!!

Comment: this works for me: `emdbook::curve3d(-3.06274*x^2-y^2+1192.22*x+152.71*y+1.829648*x*y-196494, sys3d="contour",level=0,from=c(200,200),to=c(400,500))` . You do have to specify the range manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
postscript("out.eps")
library(emdbook)
curve3d(-3.06274*x^2-y^2+1192.22*x+152.71*y+1.829648*x*y-196494,
         sys3d="contour",level=0,from=c(200,200),to=c(400,500),
        drawlabels=FALSE,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
dev.off()
```